# WPF Catch Exception thrown by User Controls inside a Window

Tags: wpf, exception, event-handling, wpf-controls

I have a couple of custom user controls inside a WPF window dialog which can throw exception. What I want to do is to purge only that window dialog when an exception is thrown by one of those user controls. However, these controls handle their own click event, so I can't find anywhere to wrap them into a try-catch from within the window itself.

The only possible workaround I can think of would be to implement an event SomethingWentWrong in my user controls, and subscribe to it within my WPF Window. However, this seems to me like a very ugly way to do things.

Is there any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global way to trap exceptions easily within a single `Window`.

You could, potentially, subscribe to [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx), which will give you a way to trap exceptions which occur on the `Dispatcher`.  This would handle most typical user interface "events", but is application wide.

Comment: Yeah, I alrealy knew for Application.DispatcherUnhandledException but it is not of much use in this case for the use I described, unfortunately.
I guess I'll have to stick to the event workaround.
I will let the question open a little longer, in case someone come up with a more elegant solution than mine, though.